# Limiting joined ForeignKey query using SQLAlchemy

Tags: python, sql, postgresql, sqlalchemy

I'm getting inaccurate results when I call `limit` on my query and I'm not sure what's causing it.

models:

```
class Voter(db.Model):
    histories = db.relationship('VoterHistory', backref='voter', lazy='dynamic')
    ncid = db.Column(db.String(80),unique=True)


class VoterHistory(db.Model):
    voter_ncid = db.Column(db.String(80), db.ForeignKey('voter.ncid'))
    election_lbl = db.Column(db.String(280))
```

example

```
q1 = Voter.query.filter_by(birth_age='25')

q2  = db.and_(Voter.histories.any(VoterHistory.election_lbl == '11/03/2015'),
      Voter.histories.any(VoterHistory.election_lbl == '03/15/2016'))

res= q1.join(Voter.histories).filter(q2)
```

If I call `.count` on `res` I get a ~4000 results. If I do `res.limit(3000).all()` I get about 700 results.

What's going on here and how can I fix it? I'm trying to get 3000 `Voter` objects.

Answer (score 0):

There are two things in play here, which together seem to produce inconsistent result:

1. `limit` applies to the `SQL` query, indeed limiting number of rows which are returned by the query
2. when you query for mapped instances, `sqlalchemy` will drop the duplicates.

In your case, setting a limit of 3000 will indeed limit the number of rows returned from the SQL to 3000 rows, but if within those 3000 rows there are only 700 *distinct* rows of the `Voter` class, only 700 such instances will be returned.

In your case the `.join(Voter.histories)` looks to be the one which introduces this *non-correspondence* between the number of rows returned from the database and the number of `Voter` instances.

---

*I hope this is clear. If not, I am happy to provide an example.*